# iPhone - XCode Target Info Creator Field

Tags: iphone, xcode, properties, versioning, target

In XCode, if I click on my Target->getInfo and go to the Properties tab I see that the Creator field has ???? in it.  Is this just simply a field to insert the name of the company/individual that is making the application or is it for something else?

Also, does the Version field drive when an .ipa file is dragged into iTunes - whether or not this version of the file replaces another version.  I ask because I recently made an adhoc distribution and when users dragged it in to iTunes even though iTunes would prompt the user about replacing the existing version, it would not replace it.  We had to delete the app, sync, re-drag and drop the .ipa, and resync.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creator code is legacy. It's something that was used in Mac OS pre X. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creator_code).

As for dragging to iTunes, I've seen the same behavior. It seems that iTunes (surprise!) has trouble figuring out that the version you dragged is newer than what you had.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the "Creator" field is obsolete.

It's been around a long, long time - back to the original Mac OS days, when companies could identify themselves with a four character creator ID.

I think it's all obsolete now - replaced by the RFC-(whatever..whatever..) compliant "Identifier".